# Cross Browser positioning/rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-8

Below is my source code for my homepage of my portfolio website. I'm am trying to center everything on this page and I have have been testing this in Safari, IE8 and Firefox. If I do not float the menu, it's proportions change drastically in IE8. Does anyone have suggestions for a centered layout in these browsers or see conflicting issues in my code?

```css
.nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav li {
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  margin: 2 2px 0 2;
  padding: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: inset;
  border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  border-color: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: red;
}
nav li a {
  padding: 0 14px;
}
nav li:hover {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.vs {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: white;
}
p a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
html {
  font-family: sans;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 460px;
  background-color: 63737e;
}
.video {
  width: 100%;
}
.sri {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
hr {
  color: red;
  border-style: dotted;
}
#content h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
p {
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.ribbon {
  float: right;
}
.design {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
}
.design2 {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.footer img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
}
.background {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 100px;
  border-color: 2f363b;
  background-color: 2f363b;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOC TYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>vslateart.com</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="background" />
  <header>
    <div class="nav" />
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.vslateart.com/index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.vslateart.com/logos-page.html">Logos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.vslateart.com/clothing-and-apparel.html">Clothing & Apparel</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.vslateart.com/miscellaneous-art.html">Miscellaneous Art</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.vslateart.com/3d-design.html">3D Design</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.vslateart.com/biography.html">Bio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.vslateart.com/contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <br>
  <div class="vs" />
  <img src="http://www.vslateart.com/images/VS Logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="VS Logo">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="intro" />
  <h1>Welcome to VS Art!</h1>
  </div>
  <p>Vincent Slate is a graphic artist in Phoenix, Arizona who specializes in logo design, web design,
    <br>clothing and merchandise design and 3D visual design. Proficient in Adobe Photoshop, Illustrator, 3ds Max
    <br>and many other software programs, Vincent's creative approach to the world of digital art has no limits. <a href="http://www.vslateart.com/biography.html">READ MORE...</a>
  </p>


  <h1>Services</h1>
  <div class="video" />
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.vslateart.com/video/homepage-services0.swf" width="1000" height="600">

    <param name="movie" value="http://www.vslateart.com/video/homepage-services0.swf" />

  </object>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="sri" />
  <img src="http://www.vslateart.com/images/sri-logo-website.jpg" width="1000" height="250" alt="SRI Logo">
  </div>

  <p><strong>Starkweather Roofing, Inc. Logo:</strong> This logo was designed for Starkweather Roofing, one of the leading commercial roofing companies in Phoenix, Arizona. This logo was displayed on a banner at Chase Field, Home of the Arizona Diamondbacks
    in 2013! For more information on Starkweather Roofing, Please visit: <em><a href="http://www.starkweatherroofing.com/">Starkweather Roofing Official Website</a>
</em>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <h1>Official Trail of Painted Ponies Artist</h1>
    <br>

    <div class="design" />
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.vslateart.com/images/the-nights-watch.jpg">
      <img src="http://www.vslateart.com/images/the-nights-watch.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="The Nights Watch">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="design2" />
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.vslateart.com/images/Process-figurine.jpg">
      <img src="http://www.vslateart.com/images/Process-figurine-cropped.jpg" width="475" height="250" alt="The Nights Watch-Process">
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.vslateart.com/images/Process-back.jpg">
      <img src="http://www.vslateart.com/images/Process-back-cropped.jpg" width="475" height="250" alt="The Nights Watch-Back">
    </a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p>Vincent Slate became an Official <em>The Trail of Painted Ponies</em> Artist with his design, <em>"The Night's Watch."</em> This "Painted Pony" design won Third Place in the online voting for the <em>Magical Art Competition</em>, hosted by The Trail of
      Painted Ponies. It was then specifically selected to be made into a figurine.
      <em>"The Night's Watch"</em> will be crafted into a figurine and released in Fall 2015, available on shelves near you! For more information on <em>The Trail of Painted Ponies</em> and their design competitions, please click on the following link:
      <em><a href="http://www.trailofpaintedponies.com/">The Trail of Painted Ponies Official Website</a></p></em>

      <div class="ribbon" />
      <img src="http://www.vslateart.com/images/ribbon.png" width="80" height="125" />
      <div>




        <!-- Add jQuery library -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Add fancyBox -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
          });
        </script>
</body>
<footer>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/VSlateArt/154385924572554?ref=bookmarks" />
  <img src="http://www.vslateart.com/images/Facebook_Logo.png" width="80" height="80" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=191083044&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile">
    <img src="http://www.vslateart.com/images/linkedin_logo.png" width="80" height="80" />
  </a>
</footer>
</div>

</html>
```

–  vslateart 31 mins ago

Comment: This questions seems more fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AkosBannerth [codereview.se] is for code which is working as intended.  It's not perfectly clear whether this code is working as intended.  Is it?  Or is there an issue with alignment?

Comment: @nhgrif I wrote my suggestion because the question itself ("Does anyone have suggestions for a centered layout in these browsers or see conflicting issues in my code?") seemed more like a request for a review, but you're right, it's not clear whether or not it is working as intended.

Comment: @AkosBannerth "If I do not float the menu, it's proportions change drastically in IE8." - sounds like there is something that's not working properly to me

Comment: @AkosBannerth I had everything originally positioned with relative and absolute positioning and this was fine in at least Firefox. I had a couple things aligned incorrectly in Safari, but IE8 was a mess. I noticed that by floating my menu to the left, the proportions were corrected, but now my menu is floated to the left in all browsers, when I intend for everything to be centered. Hope that clears it up a bit.